# GitHub Action YAML loop through JSON data

Tags: json, yaml, github-actions

I am very much new to GitHub action and YAML programming. Is there any easy method to parse JSON from a file and loop through different jobs/steps in Action. Currently I am using static values in Matrix but with increased data its not feasible to maintain.
**Example JSON: repos.json**

```
{
    "github_repos": [
        {
            "repo_name": "repo1",
            "clone_repo": "template1"
        },
        {
            "repo_name": "repo2",
            "clone_repo": "template2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My Current workflow: as an example**

```
name: "GitHub Repo Create"
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions: write-all

jobs:
  create-repo:
    name: "create repo"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        repo:
          - repo1
          - repo2

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
          
      - name: Create Repos
        run: |
          gh repo create {{ matrix.repo }} --private

  list-repo:
    name: "list repo"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        repo:
          - repo1
          - repo2

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
          
      - name: List Repos
        run: |
          gh repo edit {{ matrix.repo }} --default-branch master
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about your complete use case? What is `repos.json`? How do you want to populate your workflow with it?

Comment: I would like to run workflow steps in a loop with key,values. So as in repos.json, the workflow should create 2 repository with their respective clone repos.

Comment: One possible solution could be to read that JSON file in a separate job, set those values as `matrix` in an [output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter), and use that to populate the `matrix` of the next job. You may find similar threads. See [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).